# How Can I create animations like on this website?

Tags: css, web, animation

I found this really cool website: https://somint.art/Blueprint
and I wonder how they create those really cool animations, like the text that moves everywhere when you hover the mouse.

Are they using CSS, or is it like a javascript or something else? I tried looking at his code but i don't see anything on the references.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this website is using [pixijs](https://pixijs.io/) library to get this animations.

you can check out it's examples from [here](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-advanced/collision-detection.js)